# Mongodb: Performance impact of $HINT

Tags: mongodb, indexing, query-optimization

I have a query that uses compound index with sort on "_id". The compound index has "_id" at the end of the index and it works fine until I add a `$gt` clause to my query.

i.e, 
Initial query

`db.colletion.find({"field1": "blabla", "field2":"blabla"}).sort({_id:1}`

Subsequent queries

`db.colletion.find({"field1": "blabla", "field2":"blabla", _id:{$gt:ObjetId('...')}}).sort({_id:1}`

what I am noticing is that there are times when my compound index is not used. Instead, Mongo uses the default

`"BtreeCursor _id_"`

To avoid this, I have added a HINT to the cursor. I'd like to know if there is going to be any performance impact? since the collection already had the index but Mongo decided to use a different index to serve my query.

One thing I noticed is that when I use the hint

`"cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2,
    "nscanned" : 2,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "server" : "aaa-VirtualBox:27017",
    "filterSet" : false`

time taken is faster > millis

than when it serves the same query without hint

`"cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 3,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 3,`

Is there a trade off of using HINT which I am overlooking? Will this performance be the same on a large collection?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please specify the compound index you have created. I don't have much reputation so i couldn't ask this in comment.
But i do have a possible anwer to your question.
Mongo uses a property called "Equality-Sort-Range" which behaves in a different manner. Consider below situation-
You have few documents with fields {name : string, pin : six digit number, SSN : nine digit number} and you have two indices as -  {name: 1, pin: 1, ssn: 1} and second index is {name: 1, ssn :1, pin :1} now consider below queries:

1. `db.test.find({name: "XYZ", pin: 123456"}).sort({ssn: 1})` This query will use the first index because we have compound index in continuation. Name, pin, ssn are in continuation.
2. `db.test.find({name: "XYZ", pin: {$gt :123456"}}).sort({ssn: 1})` You will expect that first index will be used in this query. But surprisingly seconds index will be used by this query because it has a range operation on pin.

Equality-sort-range property says that query planner will use the index on field which serve - "equality-sort-range" better. Second query has range on pin so second index will be used while first query has equality on all fields so first index will be used.