# MongoDB match index vs no index - aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My collection has 10M documents, and has a field named movieId; the document has this structure:

```json
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("589bed43e3d78e89bfd9b779"), 
  "userId" : 1, 
  "movieId" : 122, 
  "rating" : 5, 
  "timestamp" : 838985046, 
  "newId" : 0.0
}
```

- MovieId is a number between 1-7000.
- I have two versions of this collection (duplicates); the first one has an index over movieId:

```js
db.collection.createIndex({movieId:1});
```

- the other version does not have this index.

I am running the following query (VarSize is just a variable):

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
[{
    $match:{"movieId":{$lte:VarSize}}
}]);`
```

I am comparing this query performance, but when `VarSize` is little, querying the collection with the index is faster (1-2 seconds), while querying the collection without the index takes 14 seconds. But when `VarSize` is big, more than 1000, querying the indexed collection is slower than the unindexed collection; querying the indexed collection takes two times longer.

Update #1:
[image: Match performance]

Update #2:
The "toArray" helped me to get increasing values while VarSize is getting bigger. Without it I think that the return values is just a cursor. 
[image: Match over collection without index]

Comment: You have documents with just one field `movieId`? What about `_id` field?

Comment: Can you show an example document from your collection, and confirm exactly what the index is?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy yes there is _id field but I think it doesn´t matter in the performance of the query even with many other fields.

Comment: @VinceBowdren the document has this structure:
**{
    "_id" : ObjectId("589bed43e3d78e89bfd9b779"),
    "userId" : 1,
    "movieId" : 122,
    "rating" : 5,
    "timestamp" : 838985046,
    "newId" : 0.0
}**

Comment: Now I have more fields but it doesn´t change the results. I created the index with **db.collection.createIndex({movieId:1});**

Comment: Thanks Johan Durán; I've taken the liberty of editing your question to include the additional information in your comments. Remember, on this site you are encouraged to [edit] and re-edit your questions and answers, to improve them as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be pretty straight. First of all it is not a covered query else you will get better perf. with indexed coll. Here you are selecting full document which have movie id and _id as well.
Sticking to basics I will try to explain what might be happening in DB -
Consider there are only 10 docs in db and movie id are sequential values (even if they are not then also it will be ok but i am considering sequential just for understanding purpose)

1. You give varSize = 2 so it needs to fetch only docs having movie id 0, 1, 2 so it needs to check three index keys and go to db and fetch those corresponding three docs from db. This all is when you have index. When you don't have index then it's simple collection scan checking all docs. So without index it's time taking.
2. Case two- you give varSize=9 so you indirectly asking all the documents. In indexed collection, it will first check all ten indices entries and then will fetch all docs corresponding to those 10 index entries. So even though you wanted all docs, it went to index and then fetched docs. While in non index environment it directly goes to collection and compares varSize with movie id and fetches the doc. So time is saved here which is getting wasted in checking index entries.

Note - Here in case 2, I took varSize =9 just to explain the issue better. I think if varSize = maxMovieId then it won't use index even in indexed collection. But if varSize is somewhat till 70 or 80% value then it will try to use index thinking it will be faster but will end up consuming more time. 
Again, query planner will eventually recognize that it is taking more time for queries where varSize is towards maxMovieId so it will NOT use index even for indexed collection. But we can't tell when it will happen as query planner runs querues in background and checks various plans at timed internal behind the scenes.

Summarizing, index work "not very straight" when you do range query. Perhaps that's why they have [equality-sort-range rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871998/mongodb-performance-impact-of-hint/42875033#42875033).

EDIT: I was right, here are my testing results-

- I added 10 M document with structure {_id: ObjectID, "a": 1} using for loop and "a" value was increasing by 1 each time with a new doc. Without index, when I query any value with a:$lte it takes almost same time ~ 650 ms on my machine. Even for a:$lte=1 it took same time. So time taken is linear when there is no index because it has to check each and every document. If you closely look executionStats output then you will realise that we have only one stage which is COLLSCAN. In this stage we are simply checking all 10M docs.
- I executed same explain on same collection after index {a:1}. And results were all together different. When a:$lte=10 or a:$lte=100 then it is taking time around 47 ms. But if I give a:$lte=1000000 then it took 1442 ms which it almost 2.5 times what it took without index. And I got the reason after checking executionStats output. It has two stages now. IXSCAN and FETCH which is time taking compared to single stage COLLSCAN.

I don't understand your graph now, I think it is wrong or you are not able to explain it clearly or some info is missing from graph. Orange line can't take less time with 10M docs. Can you clarify where it is taking varSize into consideration because when we do a range query then range value matters a lot.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Now, it´s true, there is always this step to go through the index and in some cases it´s not the most efficient. But, in this image I show my results [comparisson graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2tBs.png). I think that indexed collection results are corrects. But no indexed collection will never decrease in the graph. First becouse it always has to ask to all docuements and second becouse with VarSize bigger, bigger is the number of documents to return. I have try with different kinds of collections and I got the same results. I also saw stats to check the index use.

Comment: But no index coll. time is decreasing as per your graph.

Comment: What do you mean with index coll?

Comment: I meant that as per your graph, orange line shows no- index collection (collection which doesn't has index) time and it is decreasing...

Comment: But it doesn´t have to decrease (For me). Becouse it´s asking for all documents (however) but in addition it´s fetching more documents. I agree that near to Max VarSize no-index will be better, but no-index line doen´t have to decrease while is increasing the amount of documents to fetch.

Comment: You are right, but I cant get similar results. Can you show me how did you get te execution time? I am using a js function with new Date before and after and I am using db.collecion.aggregate(---).toArray(); because without the "toArray()" I only fetch kind of pointer or cursor and not all the real data. The explain is not useful for me becouse I need the "toArray" and don't work together. Thank you.

Comment: Edited my question update 2. About the way I'm querying now**. Now I am getting reasonable results in one point of the graph index turn slower, but no index never decrease, like expected. Thank you @lovegupta

Comment: I think i answered your original question as best as i could. It is better to put a new question for the updates you have done coz it has changed things. Initially i could see it wasn't an array. I can surely tell my results explanation - inserted 10M docs with a:1...a:10....a:10000000 and then created index {a:1}